# Python3 Pandas how do I select a column with a specific date (2022-10-01) as the header?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

Imported an excel spreadsheet that needs a lot of cleanup. The problem is that there are **date fields mixed in with standard string headers**. So I have a column with 'Name', 'Team', and then datetime dates. When I want to rename a date field I get the error message

```
KeyError: "['2022-10-01', '11/1/2022', '12/1/2022'] not in index"
```

I'm trying to select the specific column:

```
df = df[['2022-10-01', '11/1/2022', '12/1/2022']]
```

But since the key error I can't seem to rename it.  I tried list(df.columns.values) and see that the result is:
`datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 1, 0, 0)`

Is there a way I can convert these datetime headers into string format so I can rename them?  I tried various date formats but there might be a pythonic way to handle these headers.

Comment: try doing `df = df.rename(str,axis=1)` first which will convert all columns to string values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the `datetime` columns to string using `strftime`:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   2022-10-01  2022-11-01  2022-12-01
0           1           2           3
1           4           5           6
```

---

Then `print(df.columns)` will print:

```
Index(['2022-10-01', '2022-11-01', '2022-12-01'], dtype='object')
```

---

EDIT:

If you have many mixed type columns, you can do:

```py
df = df.rename(lambda c: c if isinstance(c, str) else str(c).rsplit(maxsplit=1)[0], axis=1)
```

This will check if column type is string, and if not convert it to string, split it from the right side (`.rsplit`) once (`maxsplit=1`). This will convert the datetime column to only date (discarding the seconds).

Comment: I'll try that and give you a response.  Will converting the columns to strftime("%Y-%m-%d") spoil my other text columns that have Name, Code, etc?  I'll check.

Comment: @ArthurD.Howland You can try then `df = df.rename(str,axis=1)` as stated in the comments, but you have to cut the seconds part from the column names after that.

Comment: I get: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'strftime'.  There are mixed columns, only some of them are datetime.  So far my workaround is to rename them by position:  df.columns.values[36] = "2022-10-01".  Is there a way to apply the rename only to the datetime columns?

Comment: @ArthurD.Howland Maybe try `df = df.rename(lambda c: c if isinstance(c, str) else str(c).rsplit(maxsplit=1)[0], axis=1)` ?

Comment: that works!  Please submit as answer and I'll mark it.  What does str(c).rsplit(maxsplit=1) mean?  Looks like you were able to remove the splits in the column name?  Clever.